# Remainder Theorem

Tags: number-theory

Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree greater than two. If $P(x)$ is divided by $(x-a)(x-b)$, the remainder is $$\Big( \frac{P(a) -P(b)}{a-b} \Big)(x-a) + P(a)$$

Proof:

By the remainder theorem, $P(x) = q_1(x)(x-a) + P(a)$ and $P(x) = q_2(x)(x-b) + P(b)$. Similarily, $P(x) = q_3(x)(x-a)(x-b) + cx + d$. We know that $P(a) = ca +d$ and $P(b) = cb +d$, therefore $$c = \frac{P(a) - P(b)}{a-b}$$. Solving for $d$ in the previous equation yields $$d =P(a) -a \Big( \frac{P(a) - P(b)}{a-b} \Big)$$ Now since the remainder is simply $cx+d$, we obtain $$cx + d \to P(a) -a \Big( \frac{P(a) - P(b)}{a-b} \Big) + x\Big( \frac{P(a) - P(b)}{a-b} \Big) + P(a) $$ which is trivially rewritten as $$(x-a)\Big( \frac{P(a) - P(b)}{a-b} \Big) + P(a)$$

Now is it possible to derive such an identity for something of the form

$P(x) = q_1(x)(x-r_1) + P(r_1)$
$P(x) = q_1(x)(x-r_1) + P(r_2)$
            .
            .
.
$P(x) = q_1(x)(x-r_1) + P(r_n)$

Therefore $$P(x) = q_I(x) \prod_{i\in I} (x-i) + \sum_{|I| - 1} a_wx^w + d$$ ?
  Because you'd get a system of equations like
$$P(r_1) = \sum_{|I| -1} a_w (r_1)^w + d$$
$$P(r_2) = \sum_{|I| -1} a_w (r_n)^w +d $$
.
.
.
$$P(r_n) = \sum_{|I| -1} a_w (r_n)^w +d$$

Comment: Do you know the lagrange interpolation formula?

Comment: @CalvinLin No sir

Comment: [Here](https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/lagrange-interpolation-formula/) is a link to a writeup. The remainder has degree $r-1$, and you know $r$ of it's values at the points $r_i$, so you have enough information to create the polynomial uniquely.

Answer (score 1):

By the remainder theorem we have 
$$P(x)=Q(x)(x-a)(x-b)+R(x)\tag{1}$$
where $$\deg R<\deg (x-a)(x-b)=2$$
hence $R$ is a polynomial that has at most the degree $1$ so we can put $R$ on the form
$$R(x)=\alpha(x-a)+\beta,\qquad \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb R$$

We substitute in $(1)$ $x$ by $a$ we find that $\beta=P(a)$ then we substitute in $(1)$ $x$ by $b$ we find $$\alpha=\frac{P(b)-P(a)}{b-a}$$
hence we conclude.